# How to access an integer value from a .ini file in C?

Tags: c, configuration, ini

I am trying to access values from my .ini file into my main program. The ini file just contains some values and looks like this:

```
 [number]
 jump =4
 [letters]
 key=H,E,L,L,O
```

I access it in my main program as

```
 LPCSTR file= "C:Users:\\work\\Inifile.ini";
 char returnletters[100];
 int returnjumpvalue;

 GetPrivateProfileString("letters", "key", 0, returnletters, 100, file);
 GetPrivateProfileInt("number","jump",0,returnjumpvalue, file); 

 printf("The letters are %s", returnletters);
 printf("The number is %d", returnjumpvalue);
```

THe printf statement is to verify that I read the right values for the ini file. However here the return letters give the right values, but I dont understand the usage of GetPrivateProfileInt

```
 returnletters= H,E,L,L,O
```

I dont understand this. Can somebody tell me what is wrong here?
The [GetPrivateProfileInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is here.

Comment: @SouravGhosh its a windows API. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724345(v=vs.85).aspx). And the OP's call is wrong anyway. (count the parameters).

Comment: @Goldengirl Your invoke is rather pointless for that API. The API is used as a value-fetch, and the *return* value (which you're not using at all) will either return your provided default value or the given app-key value if present and a viable `int`. Your invoke throws away the return value, and doesn't make sense anyway, as the actual API uses 4 parameters, not 5.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thank you..I spotted the mistake in my parameters. So without the variable name how do I access the value '4' from my ini file? I mean as you said where is the return value then stored for this particular call

Comment: @Goldengirl `returnjumpvalue = GetPrivateProfileInt("number", "jump", 0, file);`

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thank you. That was so stupid of me to not declare the variable like that. Thanks again :)

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry sir I am not much aware with windows. I somehow determined that the problem maybe with that function (call) itself, and I think, I'm not wrong in that case. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
returnjumpvalue = GetPrivateProfileInt("number","jump",0, file);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Return value
>
> The return value is the integer equivalent of the string following the
>   specified key name in the specified initialization file. If the key is
>   not found, the return value is the specified default value.